# I want to apply windowSoftInputMode:adjustResize to only some views in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to apply adjustResize to only some views in compose.

```
Text

TextField1

TextField2

Button
```

When the keyboard is visible, I want to keep the title position and button position, and move only the TextFields above the keyboard.

I tried applying the windowSoftInputMode:adjustPan option.

When the keyboard is visible, the position of the button is fixed, but the title is not visible.

If I tried applying adjustResize, then the position of the title is fixed, but the title is moved.

Is there a way?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?